# How to fix an end expected error near eof

Tags: lua, roblox

I made a cash for kill script in Roblox, but wanted to go further than that and implement a script where when a player has a gamepass, then that player would recieve more cash than another normal player would.

This is for a battle royale styled game in Roblox, and when I playtested it, there were no errors, but the script didn't work.

```
game.Players.PlayerAdded:connect(function(player)
    local folder = Instance.new("Folder",player)
    folder.Name = "leaderstats"
    local currency1 = Instance.new("IntValue",folder)
    currency1.Name = "Cash"

    local increment = 50

    if game:GetService("MarketplaceService"):PlayerOwnsAsset(player,7382818)then 
        increment = increment + 50
    end

    player:WaitForChild("Humanoid").Died:connect(function()
        local tag = player.Humanoid:FindFirstChild("creator")
        if tag ~= nil then
            local killer = tag.Value
            if killer ~= nil then
                -- Find the killer's leaderstats folder
                local killerStats = killer:FindFirstChild("leaderstats")

                if killerStats ~= nil then
                    -- Find the killer's Cash IntValue
                    local killerCash = killerStats:FindFirstChild("Cash")

                    -- Increase cash as before
                    killerCash.Value = killerCash.Value + increment
                end
            end
        end
    end)
```

I expected a VIP player, who has the gamepass, to receive more cash, but when I tested it, no player received any cash for killing another player at all.

Comment: You did not close the outer (or the inner) function

Comment: you close ```player:WaitForChild("Humanoid").Died:connect(function()``` with ```end)``` but you do not close ```game.Players.PlayerAdded:connect(function(player)``` with ```end)```

Answer (score 1):

> How to fix an end expected error near eof

If the Lua interpreter complains about a missing `end` you`re missing it somewhere.

Read through your code and make sure everything that is supposed to be closed with an `end` has one. Read through the Lua Reference Manual to find out which keywords need an `end`.

In your code it's if statements and function definitions. Checking each pair from inside out you'll end up one `end)` short to close this `game.Players.PlayerAdded:connect(function(player)` as mentioned in the comments.